# Arduino ATMega2560 use Assembler instead of C

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr

I have an Arduino board ATmega2560 and I would like to code assembler on it. I made some code in C for showing the temperature on an LCD16x2 using a temperature sensor. But I'd like to code the same functionality but in Assembler this time. I'm pretty new to assembler and I'd like to know how should I start doing it and maybe there's someone who can help me converting my current code into Assembler? I couldn't find that many tutorials for this board.
My C code is the following :

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int tim = 50;                       //the value of delay time
// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13);
int thermistorPin = 0;           // thermistor connected to analog pin 3

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);    // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.clear();         //Clears the LCD screen and positions the cursor in the upper-left corner 
}

void loop() 
{
   float a = analogRead(thermistorPin);
  //the calculating formula of temperature
  float resistor = (1023.0*10000)/a-10000;
  float tempC = (3435.0/(log(resistor/10000)+(3435.0/(273.15+25)))) - 200.00;

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); // set the cursor to column 0, line 0
  lcd.print(" THIS IS A TEST ");// Print a message of "Temp: "to the LCD.

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1); // set the cursor to column 0, line 0
  lcd.print("  Temp: ");// Print a message of "Temp: "to the LCD.
  lcd.print(tempC);// Print a centigrade temperature to the LCD. 
  lcd.print(" C  "); // Print the unit of the centigrade temperature to the LCD.
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: that is a major effort, the floating point alone.  set your goals a little more realistic for first efforts with assembly language, and probably start with an instruction set simulator.   try blinking an led.  and yes it is very doable, you can generate binaries from assembly language and you can maybe use the arduino tools but certainly there are others or not hard to make your own to program the board with your program.

Comment: I think a well known instruction set simulator is simavr.  I think my simple asm programs for the arduino/avr are like 20 lines of code to blink an led.  need to enable the port for output and then set or clear the bit, most of the code is counting to a big enough number between blinks that you can see the led changing.

Comment: If you understand binary numbers, you could use fixed-point arithmetic in assembly as a way to learn some asm.  Or maybe write fixed-point code in C and look at compiler output as a starting point to see how it implemented things.  AVR doesn't have an FPU, so `float` operations will compile into function calls to software floating point.